# iOS - The DetailView's navigation area is gone when using Replace segue

Tags: ios, segue

I exercise some sample project for iPad app.

It's a typical Master-Detail example which has some list of items and show details when user select item.

Using replace segue looks good. However a navigation area is disappeared, so I can't select other item any more. (On landscape mode, MasterView always shows. So it's okay but it is not a best situation.)

It's welcome for any advice.

Thank you in advance.